# Need a way to connect multiple devies to a legacy router with lower latency

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have my home network with a DSL(Digital Subscriber Line) connection, it's a very old technology, there are other ISPs with fiber, I have them too, actually, I have 2 connections with Fiber but the problem with the ISPs providing Fiber connectivity is that they don't provide static IP in my area which I need to monitor my servers remotely.

**TLDR:** I have to use a DSL connection in 2021.

**Now the problem is:** The routers compatible with DSL connection are pretty old and don't support new techniques for faster connection to multiple devices like MIMO, as do some of the newer routers that take WAN input as Fiber/RJ-45. This causes bad latency issues for my servers and other connected devices using that ISP(I have to use all of them with that ISP as I need Static IP). I have enough bandwidth (80 Mbps), so that isn't an issue. Seamlessly keeping multiple devices connected is!

I tried with 2-3 devices and it worked like charm even with this DSL router which is older than the 2010s, but the problems start to creep in as I connect 8+ devices as I need 20-30 for my work.

**So, my question is:** Is there a way I can use a MIMO router with a DSL line or use any media converter like there is for Fiber to RJ-45 and vice versa? Anything that can help my connected devices have better reception and connectivity overall and lower latency.

**Also, I am curious to know** if the connectivity issues will disappear if I use a 32 port switch and connect all my servers via LAN cables? That would be one heck of a task but please let me know if devices connected via LAN don't get latency issues.

**PS:** I know I can connect a MIMO router after the main router in my network but that'll cause double NAT and increase packet hop, all the stuff I don't want. My router has a Public IPv4, so it's my gateway to the internet, all I need for my work.

Comment: Does your DSL modem not have an Ethernet out? Just connect that into any modern equipment you choose.

Comment: Yes it has, four 100 MiB/s ethernet outs, but as I said, I don't want double NAT. And, if I use it in extender mode, the router will still be my old one, so the DHCP functionality will be done by that router only.

Comment: Can you not put your modem in bridge mode, then setup your new router to do the PPPoE or whatever authentication is necessary for the DSL? That is really your only other option. You are saying at 20-30 devices things go awry, this is probably the limits of the old DSL modem, so make it a dumb bridge and setup your static IP on your new router. This is common scenario.

Comment: There are plenty of modern DSL/PPPoE  routers, but if those arent an option, why not disable the modem's WiFi and connect a modern access point ? And if all of these servers are that vital, you should really consider using cabling.

Comment: Your question is very flawed and makes a lot if wrong assertions. It should also be broken up into multiple questions. That said - Some thoughts  - make your DSL router into a device that just strios the dsl and connect that to your core router - depending on how dsl delivers there are different ways of doing this including setting your dsl router to half bridge mode and using it to strip the encapsulation and deliver ppp to your core router   Seoerately, if wifi us your issue you can use a regular (dsl or eth router) and access points to convert eth to wifi...

Comment: Very often the problem with routers us crap firmware. Getting a router that runs something like dd-wrt, openwrt or tomato makes many routers more srable and remives the cap on the number of supported devices (but there is paltry dsl support - so a dsl modem/router -> *wrt ethernet router.  ) Using ethernet where possible will result in faster  more reluable connections and allow better use of wifi spectrum.

Comment: You could also use get a static IP in combination with your FO line by signing up for a proxy or VPN service e.g. AirVPN

Comment: @davidgo Thanks, I'll update it to multiple parts. Yes Wi-fi is exactly my issue, the thing is I start to get a delay when many devices are connected. I've got what you and acejavelin have told and will try it.
Also, do devices connected over LAN don't experience similar issues like wireless devices do? Please let me know.
Please list the assertions you think are wrong.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible problems here - the issue could be caused by 1 or both.

Specifically, if you are having problems using more then 8 devices the issue could be with the firmware in the router.  Very often cheap devices are not good at doing connection tracking.  If this is the problem then the solution is to either replace the device with a better router or turn the router into a bridge and put a decent router in place.  From a POV of connection tracking issues, if you are getting a second router any ethernet router that can run dd-wrt will do - dd-wrt does not have issues with lots of clients and is typically more robust then the software routers come with.

The Second issue - and this is where my money is - is the WIFI.  WIFI is convenient - and thats about all it has going for it.  It is not reliable, and it is not (compared to wired connections) stable.   It is also half-duplex.   Also, in anything other then a farraday cage it is impossible to get anywhere near the quoted speed of WIFI.   It is unclear from your question if you get 80 mbps from your ISP or reported by your WIFI.  If its reported by your WIFI, that 80mbps is shared between all devices on your network (and 2 WIFI devices mean less then 40 mbps each or less)

As a rule, anything you can cable with ethernet you should.  This will make those devices more reliable and faster, and will reduce the amount of use of the WIFI spectrum - providing more spectrum for those devices that need it.    (Servers don't belong on WIFI).

MIMO can help, but is not a panacea.

The assertions which you made which I believe are wrong include -

- The routers compatible with DSL connection are pretty old and don't support new techniques for faster connection to multiple devices like MIMO.  There are plenty of these - to throw out the first 2 links I found - https://www.tp-link.com/au/home-networking/dsl-modem-router/archer-vr2800/  and https://www.asus.com/nz/Networking-IoT-Servers/Modem-Routers/All-series/DSLAC68U/ (If you are limiting yourself to ADSL routers, thats your problem - look for VDSL modems and just double check they work with ADSL - almost all will)
- DSL is not a very old technology. ADSL1 - ie the first varient is.   VDSL2-VPlus was only approved in 2015, and of-course was rolled out later.   To be contentious, in Australia VDSL connections are actually called fibre connections, and is the currently used method to deliver fibre to many locations - even in dense areas.
- You don't need a static IP from your ISP to monitor your servers (see below)
- Latency issues are not caused by lack of MIMO (although MIMO can mitigate the issues a bit), it is caused by using unregulated spectrum on a shared half-duplex media.

To answer your question -

An AP is a device which converts between ethernet and WIFI.   When used as an AP, the AP/Router becomes invisible in terms of traceroutes and IPV4/IPV6 connectivity, so it does not introduce any NAT issues.

You can convert most routers into AP's (access points), and plug these into a router.  To do this you connect a LAN port on the main router to a **LAN** port on the the Router/AP, and disable DHCPD.

Using ethernet [what you call LAN cables] (and a switch) to connect your router to the server is a good idea and a best practice for servers.  If you do this, try to only use 1 LAN port on the router to connect it to the switch and feed it from there.  A dirty secret of SOHO routers is they use software to create a virtual switch on the 4 ethernet ports, and this can impact performance.

**Suggestion**

I think you have asked the wrong question.  If you have both DSL and 2 ethernet connections, I put to you it would be better to re-evaluate your network and rebuild it from the ground up to support your goals.

I note you say you have DSL only for the static IP address for monitoring your servers.  You also complain about, in effect,  a crap DSL router.   I would solve both of these issues by ditching the DSL connection and router, and getting a decent ethernet router which will match your needs - and, if done smartly, will be able to balance your 2 fibre connections.

There are (at least) 2 ways I can think of to bypass the dynamic IP issue on your fibre connections -

- I would put an OpenVPN client on a decent ethernet router running DD-WRT and purchase a VPN service that offers a static IP address.   (There are lots of them - google Static IP VPN - these services can be had for less then $5 per month from reliable VPN providers)
- You could use dynamic DNS.  If you are not constantly rebooting your DSL connection, this may be good enough.

Comment: Thank you, just to add one thing, I'm getting Static IP for $2/month. I don't need to setup an OpenVPN or any proxy server for monitoring purpose as I need Static IP for many more things and it's way faster and reliable, I've literally tried everything and this is the best by far. I tried DynDNS and Static IP surpasses it by a mile for my work. Anyway, Static IP is the way to go for me. Most things you've said are right, the thing is I have a very poor model of the DSL router itself. Thank you so much for your time.